# how to install and use MVC Sitemap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

since the Sitemap of VS2008 does not work with MVC, I found MVC Sitemap by maartenba on codeplex. But how do I install and use this.. The download is a sample, and below it is a Dll. I'm sure the install is ridiculously simple, and also overlooked. So I'm looking here to see if I can get assistance using this package in my VB website.

http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/

SideNote: perhaps I should convert to a C# app...or can I just start writing my controllers in c# I do enjoy it more than VB.

Thanks

Comment: This question is unanswerable without some more information.  There's examples on the site; did you follow them?  Did you forget to add a reference to the DLL (and possibly the namespace that it lives in)?  Not touch up your web.config?  Type something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help has been added on the frontpage over at http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/.